# ajax like button success incorrect

Tags: php, ajax

I was making like button with php and ajax/jquery and it wont be reload when you click it will just reload the div but it reload the div but the number of like don't add
here my code.

```
<div id="Post-ImVi-Action"> 
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Post-ImVi-Action-Like').click(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var name = $('#Like_Poster_name').val();
          var email = $('#Like_Post_1').val();
          $.ajax
            ({
              type: "POST",
              url: "php-SocialMedia-Posting-Like.php",
              data: { "Poster_name": name, "Post_1": email },
              success: function (data) {
                $("#Post-ImVi-Action-Like").html(data);
              }
            });
        });
      });
    </script>
    <input type="Hidden" name="Poster_Name" id="Like_Poster_name" value="<?php echo $Post_Row["Poster_Name"];?>">
    <input type="Hidden" name="Post_1" id="Like_Post_1" value="<?php echo $Post_Row["Post_1"];?>">
    <input type="Hidden" name="ID" id="Like" value="<?php echo $Post_Row["ID"];?>">
    <button id="Post-ImVi-Action-View">158K</button>
    <button id="Post-ImVi-Action-Like" type="button" name="Like_Button" >
        <?php
            $Post = $Post_Row["Post_1"]; 
            $Sql_like_count = "SELECT * FROM `likes` WHERE post = '$Post'";
            $Result_like_Count = mysqli_query($conn, $Sql_like_count);
            while ($ROW_LIKE = mysqli_fetch_array($Result_like_Count)) {
                echo $ROW_LIKE['Likes'];
            }
        ?>
    </button>
    <button id="Post-ImVi-Action-Share">815</button>
    <div id="Post-ImVi-Action-Face"></div>
</div>
```

Here is php-SocialMedia-Posting-Like.php

```
<?php
include"php-MAIN-Info.php";
include"php-MAIN-SignUp+Database.php";
    $Post = $_POST['Post_1'];
    $Poster_Name = $_POST['Poster_Name'];
    $Sql = "SELECT* FROM Likes WHERE Post = '$Post' AND Poster_Name = '$Poster_Name'";
    $Like_Result = mysqli_query($conn, $Sql);
    while ($Like_Row = mysqli_fetch_array($Like_Result)) {
        $Like_Add = $Like_Row['Likes'] + '1';
        $Sql_Like_Add = "UPDATE Likes SET Likes = '$Like_Add' WHERE Post = '$Post' AND Poster_Name = '$Poster_Name';";
        $Like_Result_Add = mysqli_query($conn, $Sql_Like_Add);
        if ($Like_Result_Add) {
            echo $Like_Add;
        }
    }
```

update:
i found a error

php-Home-MSOHome.php:352 Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

please try to help cause i'm new to this web.Thanks
why is no one answering my question you k i'm still looking for the answers

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: why don't you simply return `$Like_Add` i.e : `echo $Like_Add` to ajax success and assign that value to your `div` where likes are display ? Also ,when you reload div `$Post_Row["Post_1"]` value is still null ? did you check that ?

Comment: I want to save it in the db so it won't just let 1 like only plus i did sum search but it didn't do what i like

Comment: Simply you can write `$("#Post-ImVi-Action-Like").html(data)` where data will have value which you will  be returning from php to ajax  using `echo`.

Comment: placing that in `success: function (data) {here }` or where and i don't know what are you talking about

Comment: "placing that in success: function (data) {here } or where" ... Yes that's right. That's the only place where you can receive the response

Comment: like this edit now and its still not working

Comment: for your hosts sake I hope this is not live, it's full of sql injection vectors

Comment: `onclick="function Like_button()"` doesn't belong there. You're binding the click handler with jQuery, you don't need `onclick` as well.

Comment: Sry i was useing javascript before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it its a php error  udfinde `Poster_name` its `Poster_Name`

Comment: btw error udfinde Poster_name its Poster_Name is not a error